# Loop over two lists and find matching elements using pandas python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have list A with elements `{China China USA USA ITALY FRANCE}` and list B with elements `{2018 2017 2018 2017 2018 2017}`

I want to check for element 2018 in list `B` and, once it is found, to return the corresponding element from list `A`.

With the found, elements I will populate list `C`. So the desired result is list `C` with elements `{China, USA, ITALY}`.

Comment: It's not a list. How is that a pandas question?

Comment: `[v for v,d in zip(listA, listB) if d==2018]`?

Comment: @TomWojcik you are technically rfor i in range(len(df.country)): 
        if b[i]==2018 :
            c.append(a[i])
# Print c
print(c)ight but this is my code so far:

Comment: please change your lists to this format:

`A=['China', 'China', 'USA', 'USA', 'ITALY', 'FRANCE']
B=[2018, 2017, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2017]`

As they are now, they do not represent a valid structure in python ({} indicate a set but strings must be included in quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using list comprehension itself.

```
A = ['China','China','USA','USA','ITALY','FRANCE']
B =[2018,2017,2018,2017,2018,2017]
print("List A :", A)
print("List B :", B)
ind = [i for i in range(len(B)) if B[i] == 2018]
C = [A[i] for i in ind] 
print("List C:" , C)

List A : ['China', 'China', 'USA', 'USA', 'ITALY', 'FRANCE']
List B : [2018, 2017, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2017]
List C: ['China', 'USA', 'ITALY']
```

Comment: Glad I could help Thanks @user1997567

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
A=['China', 'China', 'USA', 'USA', 'ITALY', 'FRANCE']
B=[2018, 2017, 2018, 2017, 2018, 2017]
C=[]
for i in range(len(B)):
    if i<len(A):
        if B[i]==2018:
            C.append(A[i])

print(C)

['China', 'USA', 'ITALY']
```

Comment: I would recommend doing it in a more pythonic way e.g.
`[country for country, year in zip(countries, years) if year == 2018]`

Comment: I would suggest the way above, as there are some issues with the structure of provided lists in question

Comment: The same issues will fail your code  If you want to stay with your proposition, please use at least `enumerate()`, your code is suboptimal without it.

Comment: You count the length of the `B` list to prepare the loop based on the range function whose only responsibility is to take the element from `B` again. It is the approach that is used rather in C++ instead of Python.